# Remove line break \n based on pattern

Tags: design-patterns, notepad++, line, break

I have below text:

[image]

I want to remove all the break line (\n\r) from each long text so it will in one single long text per each line as below:

[image]

I have no any idea, searching so far with no answer.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a simple replace in Notepad++, there is lots of documentation and help elsewhere. Note that CR is `\r` and LF is `\n` so the question's title and middle paragraph with `\n\r` appear to be wrong. The screenshots appear to be replacing `\n` without a '\r` with a space. If that is the requirement then please describe it clearly in the question.

Comment: Hi @AdrianHHH, you was right, it should only remove \n
Here my solution: ([0-9]{2})([\/]{1})([0-9]{2})([\/]{1})([0-9]{4}) == 01/02/2020 then replace with: \n \1\2\3\4\5